# Add-AzureInternalLoadBalancer command in "Azure Resource Manager" mode

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-virtual-network

I'm interested to achieve something like the solution which is described in [this](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/load-balancer-internal-getstarted/#end-to-end-examples-of-internal-load-balancing) post.

Therefore, I wanted to add an `Internal Load Balancer` in a MS Azure virtual network. I created a VNet in `Resource Manager` mode and added 3 VMs to it, but now I don't have access to `Add-AzureInternalLoadBalancer` powershell command in arm mode.

If I switch to `Service Management` mode, the the problem is that I don't see VMs anymore.

How can I add an internal load balancer in `Resource Manager` mode?

Answer (score 0):

Assume you have setup PS subscription and user Account.

```
# Add Load Balancer to Cloud Service wrapping VMs
Add-AzureInternalLoadBalancer -ServiceName apptier `
-InternalLoadBalancerName apptierplb -SubnetName appsubnet `
-StaticVNetIPAddress 192.168.1.25

# Add Endpoints to VMs
# VM1
Get-AzureVM -ServiceName apptier -Name apptier01 | `
Add-AzureEndpoint -LBSetName 'HttpIn' -Name 'HttpIn' `
-DefaultProbe -InternalLoadBalancerName 'apptierplb' -Protocol tcp `
-PublicPort 80 -LocalPort 80 -LoadBalancerDistribution sourceIP | `
Update-AzureVM

# VM2
Get-AzureVM -ServiceName apptier -Name apptier02 | `
Add-AzureEndpoint -LBSetName 'HttpIn' -Name 'HttpIn' `
-DefaultProbe -InternalLoadBalancerName 'apptierplb' -Protocol tcp `
-PublicPort 80 -LocalPort 80 -LoadBalancerDistribution sourceIP | `
Update-AzureVM

# You can check what distribution mode is set
Get-AzureVM –ServiceName apptier –Name apptier01 | Get-AzureEndpoint
```

Related links : 
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/load-balancer-internal-arm-powershell/

http://blog.kloud.com.au/2015/06/23/azure-internal-load-balancing-setting-distribution-mode/